# How to get textfiled value selected in Ext JS 3.4 grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

How do I get Ext JS  3.4 grid's textfield value selected on beforeedit listener function?

```
'beforeedit' : function(object) {
                    var rec = gridTilit.store.getAt(object.row);


                    var colIndex = object.column;
                    var rowIndex = object.row;
                    var cm = Ext.getCmp('grid-tilit').getColumnModel();
                    var valCol = cm.getColumnAt(colIndex);
                    var count = gridTilit.getStore().getTotalCount();

                    var cellXtype = valCol.getEditor().getXType();

                    colname = object.field;

                    if (cellXtype=="textfield") {
                        //function to select signle textfield 
                        // cell value to selected must be executed here 
                    } else {
                        rec.set(colname, "");
                    }

                },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to function helps:

```
$("input[type=text]").focus(function() { $(this).select(); });
```